# can data persist from a view to another view using $scope?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, web-applications

I have a form to get data from the user which is located in view1:

```
<form ng-submit="addClient()">
      Numero client : <br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Numero client" ng-model="newclient.numClient" /><br><br>
      Rue : <br>
      <input type="text"   placeholder="Rue" ng-model="newclient.rue" /><br><br>
      Numero de rue : <br>
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Numero de rue" ng-model="newclient.numRue" /><br><br>
      Code postal : <br>
      <input type="text"   placeholder="Code postal" ng-model="newclient.codePostal" /><br><br>
      Localite : <br>
      <input type="text"   placeholder="Localite" ng-model="newclient.localite"  /><br><br>
      <input type="submit"  value="Enregister">
    </form>
```

I'm trying to display this data I got, in another view : view2:

```
<div class="listClients" >
    <h1>Liste des clients :</h1>

      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in clients">
          <h3>{{x.numClient}} - {{x.rue}}</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

to store the data Im using local storage.
app.js: myController:

```
myApp.controller('myController',function($scope, $location, $http){

  //initialize clients with 1 client : clients is an array now
  $http.get("data/clients.json").then(function(response){
      $scope.clients = response.data;
  });

  $scope.addClient = function(){


    $scope.client = {
       numClient: parseInt($scope.newclient.numClient),
       rue: $scope.newclient.rue,
       numRue: parseInt($scope.newclient.numRue),
       codePostal: parseInt($scope.newclient.codePostal),
       localite: $scope.newclient.localite
   };
   //saves the registered client to local storage : localStorage.setItem(key,value);
   localStorage.setItem($scope.client.numClient,angular.toJson($scope.client));

   //saves from local storage to $scope.clients
   for(var i =0; i<localStorage.length; i++){
     $scope.clients.push(angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))));
   };

   console.log($scope.clients); // log 1: this log here works as expected

   //reseting newclient for future use
   $scope.newclient.numClient = "";
   $scope.newclient.rue = "";
   $scope.newclient.numRue = "";
   $scope.newclient.codePostal = "";
   $scope.newclient.localite = "";

  };

});
```

the data is saved in the array clients.
I tried to display it using  ng-repeat in the SAME view: view1 and it works ,
until I refresh the page or try to display the array from view2:  the data is gone from the array.
since I'm using localStorage I can still console log it but it is not useful.

Is there a way to make the clients array persist so I can display it from another view?

Comment: Use an angular service (or factory) to share data across different components. That service can be responsible for setting and getting from storage and/or your remote source also

Comment: thank you for the helpful comment .What part of the code would i put in the angular service ? that would be very helpful thank you.